# symfony2 adesigns calendar-bundle translation

Tags: symfony, calendar, fullcalendar, bundle, translate

I'm actually trying to use the calendar-bundle from adesigns(adesigns/calendar-bundle": "1.2-beta"), and to translate it, but it seems like it doesn't translate.

```
$('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev, next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay,'
    },
    lazyFetching: true,
    timeFormat: {
        // for agendaWeek and agendaDay
        agenda: 'h:mmt',    // 5:00 - 6:30

        // for all other views
        '': 'h:mmt'         // 7p
    },
    //Set to True to show Calendar Week in seperate Row/Field of Calendar View
    weekNumbers: false,
    //Set to your Language to change the text, the first day of week etc according to your settings.
    lang: 'fr',
```

So my calendar should be in french, but i'm still getting my months/days in english.

Is there someone who already did it ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best solution, i think that the bundle only accept 'en' because the code has been harcoded.
I recommend to you to pick up the file bundles/adesignscalendar/js/fullcalendar/jquery.fullcalendar.min.js, make a copy in your bundle, include this new file instead the other, an make all translations you need.
Also you just can add, like the parameter 'lang: es', each translation, i.e.

```
$('#calendar-holder').fullCalendar({
...
dayNamesShort : [ 'Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab' ],
...
buttonText : { prev : '&nbsp;&#9668;&nbsp;', next : '&nbsp;&#9658;&nbsp;',
        prevYear : '&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;', nextYear : '&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;',
        today : 'hoy', month : 'mes', week : 'semana', day : 'dia' },
...
});
```

I hope this can help someone.